# Why am I getting the wrong result when applying the extra strong Lucas pseudoprime test?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, primality-test, pseudoprimes

I'm trying to do the [Lucas extra strong pseudoprime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Strong_Lucas_pseudoprimes) but get the wrong result. For example $13$ is prime but the test gives composite. Here is what I tried:

$n=13$ then $n+1=14=7 \cdot 2^1$ gives $d=7$ and $s=1$.
set $P=3,Q=1,D=3^2-4=5$

$U_1=1$ and $V_1=P=3$
$U_2=3$ and $V_2=7$
$U_3=8$ and $V_3=5$
$U_6=1$ and $V_6=10$
$U_7=0$ and $V_7=11$
$U_{14}=0$ and $V_{14}=2$

There's two ways the number can be a pseudoprime 1) $U_d \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ and $V_d \equiv 2 \pmod{n}$; or 2) $V_{d2^r} \equiv 0$ for $0 \leq r < s$

We have $14=2\cdot7$ so $d=7$ For 1) $U_7$ is congruent to 0 but the second necessary condition, $V_7$ isn't congruent to 2. For 2) $V_7$ is considered again but still $11$ isn't congruent to $0 \bmod 13$. Since neither of these congruence hold, the test gives composite.

What is wrong with what I have done?

I have [heard](https://programmingpraxis.com/2014/02/04/lucas-pseudoprimes/) that the extra strong test is faster than the strong test. Is this true? I find it unlikely since it has an additional condition that must be checked, but maybe something to do with the parameters makes it end earlier.

Comment: I haven't studied Lucas primality testing much at all, but I did not see a result stating that these congruences would guarantee $n$ to be composite. AFAICT the Lucas test is based on the fact that if $n$ is a prime then the element $\alpha=(P+Q\sqrt{D})/2$ in the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{n^2}$ should have the property that $\alpha^{n+1}$ is an element of the prime subfield. The congruences $U_{n+1}=0$, $V_{n+1}=2$ simply mean that $\alpha^{n+1}$ is the identity element of the field. Apparently that is somehow exceptional. But, as you just saw, does not mean that $n$ woud be composite.

Comment: I rather think that to any odd prime $p$ and $D$ such that $D$ is a quadratic non-residue there will always exist pairs $(P,Q)$ such that $U_{p+1}=0$, $V_{p+1}=2$. This is because the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ has elements of order $p+1$. See [WP on Lucas sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence): $V_{p+1}=2, U_{p+1}=0$ is equivalent to $\alpha^{p+1}=1$, and this will always hold for some $\alpha$, that is, for some pair $(P,Q)$.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand this primality test a bit better. The case $U_{n+1}=0$, $V_{n+1}=2$ allows  us to make a slightly more refined test by verifying that repeated squaring took $\alpha^{n+1}=\alpha^{d\cdot2^s}$ from $\alpha^d$ to $1$ via $-1$ rather than by some other route (when compositeness can be concluded). Very much like doing a round of Rabin-Miller as opposed to just a round of Little Fermat. Basically to prove that a composite number is guaranteed to be exposed with a positive probability. Ii don't see all ot it yet :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the $\pm$ on the $2$ in the first condition.

A number $n$ passes the test if one of the following conditions holds:

1. $U_d \equiv 0 \pmod n$ and $V_d \equiv \pm 2 \pmod n$.
2. $V_{d \cdot 2^r} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ for some $r$, $0 \le r < s$.

In your case, $U_7 \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$ and $V_7 \equiv 11 \equiv -2 \pmod{13}$, so the first condition holds.

Comment: Any idea if it's faster than the strong version?

Comment: Presumably it requires fewer iterations on average to prove that a composite number is composite (or to be reasonably sure that it is prime) but I don't know any citations.

Answer (score 0):

The test requires a larger power of 2.

Essentially, you are looking to see if a prime 7 mod 24 is prime, the period of this divides p+1.  14 is not of this form.  You might use with 4807.

The prime test involved here is essentially the same as if $p \mid b^{p-1}-1$, for some base b, then p is a pseudoprime.

The inclusion of the jacobi determinate also includes the class-2 criterian (that $p \mid b\^\^p - b), where the double-carat represents the nth term of t_0=2, t_1=b, t(n+1)=b.t(n)-t(n-1).

The jacobi is not really necessary here, as the value at p is ascending or descending as the period is upper or lower.  The same algorithm has been used to search for instances where $p^2\mid b\^\^p - b$.

The actual isopower (which is what the ^^ is called), can be calculated at 3/2 of the speed of the ordinary power, and serching for $b$ rather than the period-marker $2$, means that there is no need to evaluate the Jacobi.

The power of 2 condition seems to be being used because the mathematicians do not have a general algorithm for finding isopowers.  It's not needed.